# Google Script - Duplicate Driver Folders Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

The below code is creating the clients specified folder in the clientFolderParent and the 3 sub folders
Client Folders
-New Client
--Sales
--Weekly
--Statements

but it is also creating all 4 new folders in the root of the drive. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

```
    var clientFolderParent =DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxx");  
  var firstLevel = clientFolderParent.createFolder(DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder));
  var secondLevel = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);
  var secondLevelID = secondLevel.next();
  var salesID = secondLevelID.createFolder(DriveApp.createFolder("Sales Order").getId());  
  var weeklyID  = secondLevelID.createFolder(DriveApp.createFolder("Weekly Invoice").getId());
  var statID = secondLevelID.createFolder(DriveApp.createFolder("Statement").getId());
```

Comment: please include your code for createFolder

Comment: createFolder is a google script method. I did not create it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the method `DriveApp` you get the root of your drive.

Therefore calling the method `var firstLevel = clientFolderParent.createFolder(DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder));` is creating 2 different folders 1 in the clientFolderParent and the other in the root (you can check that they are different by looking at the folderIDs).

You haven't provided your full code but I assume that `var driveFolder =` contains the string name that you want to name the new folder so,

change `var firstLevel = clientFolderParent.createFolder(DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder))` to `var firstLevel = clientFolderParent.createFolder(driveFolder);` and this should fix your problem. Do the same in other lines below.

This is the best I can do by guessing the code above the lines you have provided.